Delimit beginning/end of a text section (not being in a box) using visual objects, glued to text at page break
Context
I'm creating a LaTeX class for popular mathematic articles in which images play a central role. As a result, the following requirements have been set for:

the online versions of articles (standalone PDF ones),
the paper versions of the articles (volumes of collections made of selections of online articles published during the year).

Online versions of articles

Composition is done on an endless page (thanks to the standalone class) in order to :

show the figures where they are discussed: it's not a good idea for them to be far away, as this could confuse the target readers, who may be teenagers or even children,
avoid vertical blanks.


Theorems and similar are presented in boxes (based on tcolorbox). These can contain figures which, because of the endless page, can both be floats and be in TeX boxes without generating the error “Float(s) lost”.

Here is an example of such theorems and the like containing figures:

Paper versions of the articles

Composition is of course not on an endless page (e.g. book class used), and figures are therefore necessarily floating.
Theorems and the like can of course not be presented in boxes, as this is incompatible with the floating status of the figures they may contain (“Float(s) lost” error). To compensate for this, it is planned to delimit these theorems and the like, hence not by boxes, but by objects that visually mark only their beginnings and ends, visually as close as possible to those of the boxes in the online versions of the articles).

This is the difficult part and what I've tried so far is to put before (resp. after)
these theorems contents the same kind of boxes as for the online version (based
on tcolorbox), but empty and without bottom (resp. top) rules; and, by trial
and error, I moved the content thanks to \vspace*.
This method, everything but robust, can be found in the following example where:

the frame color and the font, not the same as above, don't matter,
the \pagebreak[2] for the page breaks to be encouraged between the theorems and hence, finger crossed, discouraged between the top/bottom box and the theorem's content.

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[textwidth=12cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\dummytext}{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
}

\tcbuselibrary{skins,hooks}

\newcounter{theorem}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewTColorBox[use~ counter=theorem]{theorem_start}{ O{} m }{%
  , bottomrule=0pt
  , outer~ arc=1.5mm
  , standard~ jigsaw
  , sharp~ corners=south
  , fonttitle=\bfseries
  , opacityback=0
  , IfEmptyF={#2}{after~ title={\c_space_tl(#2)}}
  , after~ title~ pre={\c_space_tl \thetcbcounter}
  , #1
}
\NewTColorBox{theorem_end}{  }{%
  , toprule=0pt
  , outer~ arc=1.5mm
  , enlarge~ top~ initially~ by=-7mm
  , opacityback=0
  , standard~ jigsaw
  , sharp~ corners=north
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{theorem}{O{}m}{
  \pagebreak[2]
  \begin{theorem_start}[title=Theorem,#1]{#2}
  \end{theorem_start}
  \setlength\leftmargini{5.5mm}
  \vspace*{-9mm}
  \begin{quote}
    \itshape
}{
  \end{quote}
  \begin{theorem_end}
  \end{theorem_end}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{lemma}{O{}m}{
  \pagebreak[2]
  \begin{theorem_start}[
    , title=Lemma
    , colback=white
    , coltitle=black
    % , interior~ titled~ engine=empty
    , titlerule=0mm
    , attach~ title~ to~ upper={.\\}
    % , title~ engine=empty
    , #1
    ]{#2}
  \end{theorem_start}
  \setlength\leftmargini{5.5mm}
  \vspace*{-11mm}
  \begin{quote}
}{
  \end{quote}
  \begin{theorem_end}
  \end{theorem_end}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{axiom}{O{}m}{
  \pagebreak[2]
  \begin{theorem_start}[
  , detach~ title
  , attach~ title~ to~ upper={.\c_space_tl}
  , coltitle=black
  , title=Axiom
  , #1
  ]{#2}
  \tl_gset:Ne \g_tmpa_tl {\tcbtitletext\csuse{tcb@insert@after@title}.}
  \end{theorem_start}
  \setlength\leftmargini{5.5mm}
  \vspace*{-11.5mm}
  \begin{quote}
    \hspace*{
      \widthof{\bfseries\g_tmpa_tl}
    }
}{
  \end{quote}
  \begin{theorem_end}
  \end{theorem_end}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}{}
  \dummytext{}
\end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}{}
  \dummytext{}
\end{lemma}
\begin{axiom}{}
  \dummytext{}
\end{axiom}
\end{document}

(On the following image, the very thin horizontal rules don't matter.)

Question
Do you see a better, more robust, method than the previous one?

If the images belong with the theorems, it is IMHO a non-starter to have the images float and the theorems not. Either don't use floats period. Or use floating tcolorboxes which include both the theorem and the (non-floating) picture. I'm betting the second will be problematic, so I'd try the first. Just forget floats. You will get sub-optimal page-breaking in some cases, so deal with these cases manually. If it is actually OK for the theorems and images to get separated - just not ideal - that's a different matter.

...  figures are therefore necessarily floating. Yes. So don't use figures. The only reason to use a figure is because you want the content to float. If you don't want it to float, the solution is simple.

Note that you cannot have an endless page in TeX. Nor can you have one several miles long. There is a hard limit set by the maximum dimension TeX can handle. If your standalone output exceeds that limit, you will have to break the page or shorten the content. Note also that there are differences between the standalone package and the standard classes which might or might not matter to you.

@cfr I tried to deal without floats but, since the images can be very numerous, it was a nightmare so the solution is not that simple. Theorems and images are not separated with the “endless pages”, precisely to make the (online) articles easier to read for young people (who are supposed to read them on their smartphone); for the paper versions of the articles, it is actually OK - but as you said, just not ideal - for the theorems and images to get separated.

@cfr About “endless” pages, I should have said that I'm aware there is a hard limit set by the maximum dimension TeX can handle, and that's unfortunate this limitation cannot be
avoided nowadays. For the articles which exceed the limit, we will either split them into two parts or insert a ling to the paper version of them.

So what does 'more robust' mean here? I took it to mean that the images wouldn't get separated from the theorems, but evidently that's a misunderstanding on my part. If you do use floats for just the images rather than the boxes, you might want to look into using float barriers to prevent them floating too far. It's hard to really know what will work for you because obviously we don't really know what the document is like. (How much text there is, for example, how large the images and theorems are etc. etc.
